# Automating CKEditor Combo Boxes using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ckeditor, selenium-chromedriver, fckeditor

Following is the CkEditor I am trying to automate on my website:

[CKEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejhdo.png)

I have automated clicking through the Bold, Italics, Subscript and Superscript buttons. However, the dropdown menu for Font color or Text style show up blank on the DOM as follows:

[DOM for CKEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYBWU.png)

As you can notice, the span underneath the combo box element is empty. Thus any of the text color options available in the combo box do not show up on the DOM. How to automate clicking through various different text colors?

Comment: It's not empty, the `A` is not expanded. What's inside after you expand it? Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML. Please post the HTML as text instead of an image.

Comment: @JeffC I cannot provide the internal link from my employer. However, let's consider the following example:

http://ckeditor.com/

I want to automate the article editor provided on this page. In the "Styles" dropdown menu, I want to select "Greyscale Image". How can I identify the web element? The DOM is blank for this element and has no reference of it. I can define the Styles menu as a page object as follows: 

    public static WebElement Styles(WebDriver driver){
  element = driver.findElement(By.className("cke_combo_button"));
  return element;
 }

But how can I select a style?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that at least this dropdown is inside an iframe. You have to switch context into that iframe before you can select something in the dropdown. The code below is working for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Formatting Styles']")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("cke_72_frame");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Borderless Table']")).click();
```

Comment: According to our dev team, the cke_72_frame in my application is dynamic. The next time you try clicking on it, the same could be named cke_60_frame. What to do?

Comment: I'm not sure that is true. When I tried refreshing the page a few times on the ckeditor.com page, the ID never changed. I would load your internal page and try it a few times and see if it changes. If it does, you'll have to find another unique way to locate the iframe. You can do that by index or find a name or class to use.

Comment: Jeff, I see your point when I tried locating the element in Firefox using Firebug. However, I am unable to see the name of iframes in Chrome. Unfortunately our application is only optimized for Chrome. Do you know how to see this iframe in the Dev tools?

Comment: You should be able to just search the HTML for "iframe" or you can run a CSS selector like `$$("iframe")` or something like that.

Comment: Great.. I am working on it. Thank you so much for your help on this. You saved me from switching from Selenium to some record and playback tool. Haha..

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!